# How to draw image on whole page with gdi+

Tags: c++, image, printing, gdi+

I have to print JPG on default printer. I use winapi and gdi+. My image isn't draw on whole page. How can I do this? Somebody helps?

```
for ( UINT i = 0; i < frameCount; i++ )
{
  StartPage(hDC);

  image.SelectActiveFrame(&pageGuid, i);
  graphics.SetPageUnit(UnitInch);

  width = image.GetWidth() / image.GetHorizontalResolution();
  height = image.GetHeight() / image.GetVerticalResolution();
  graphics.DrawImage(&image,
                      0.f,
                      0.f,
                      width,
                      height);

  EndPage(hDC);
}
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: try using some numbers for width and height instead of your calculated values.  observe what happens.  then figure out what numbers you really need as a function of the page...